# Spin-Position Coupling/Interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Firstly, is there a general procedure/algorithm for attacking Hamiltonians having spin-position coupling, e.g., 
$$\frac{\mathbf{\sigma_1}\cdot\mathbf{\sigma_2}}{|\mathbf{r_1}-\mathbf{r_2}|}$$

I do not know where to begin.

Secondly, I would like you to recommend a textbook which discuss such a kind of systems. I looked out and found none.

Comment: Is it a many-body problem or a two-body problem? In the latter case, this is just a more complicated version of the hydrogen atom, that should be solvable easily using the appropriate basis for the spin variables.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?  That will help us tell you where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a spin-spin problem in a two-body system. As far as bound states are concerned, you may have a look at the Breit equation, where such terms are encountered. You may find a quite detailed discussion on it in Bethe&Salpater book "Quantum Mechanics of one- and two-electron atoms", pg 170. For a non-relativistic treatment, you may have a look at http://people.ccmr.cornell.edu/~clh/p654/MM-Lec0.pdf . If you look at Eq. 4.1.23, it is a spin-spin coupling term very similar to what you propose.

How this hamiltonian is attacked: I believe that what is usually done is reducing these kind of terms to the total spin, which is normally a conserved quantity. You may use $\vec \sigma_1\cdot \vec \sigma_2=(\vec \sigma_1+\vec \sigma_2)^2/2- 1/2(\vec \sigma_1^2 + \vec \sigma_2^2)$. The three operators in the right hand side are conserved operators in a two-body system. So, you can easily act on the two-body wavefunction extracting their eigenvalues.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I don't have the rep to comment, but I'd take a look at [Ising models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model).